# How to turn popovercontroller direction arrow off

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to present a popovercontroller without an direction arrow:

> UIPopoverArrowDirection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can, or at least could, (I am not sure if the trick still works in the latest SDK ) just pass `0`

Answer (score 1):

Use this 
`[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(440.0, 80.0, 150.0, 140.0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];`